# Excel auto filter criteria value is being set wrong?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to apply an auto filter to my excel worksheet and I'm trying to figure out how to only display certain criteria values.

The following code which many suggest should achieve what I want.

```
Expression.Range(A1:G1).Autofilter(5, '=Array("value", "value")', xlFilterValues, None, True)
```

The following documentation can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx

The code executes but it doesn't select the criteria listed in the array. When I open up the workbook and look at the custom filter it displays this value next to the equals drop down menu:

= Array("value", "value")

So how do I go about getting the values selected and displayed like you would manually in excel? The only solutions I can seem to find is using the array function but I'm not having any luck with it.

Comment: I think the syntax in your post is a little off. Try `Expression.Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter 5, Array("value", "value"), xlFilterValues, None, True`

Comment: Yeah I became a bit lazy and didn't add the quote marks.

Comment: If it's jsut the 2 values why not use the `xlAnd` operator?

Comment: There are roughly five values currently and I'm trying to future proof it by using an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to set the `Criteria` as an array:

```vb
Sub qwerty()
    Dim Expression As Range

    Set Expression = Range("A1:G1")
    ary = Array("value1", "value2")
    Expression.AutoFilter 5, ary, xlFilterValues, None, True
End Sub
```

While this works, I never do it this way *(I always name the parameters)*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure I tried this earlier but instead of passing the whole array I decided to loop through each index in the array which didn't work.